# MS word html file not fitting in page layout

Tags: html, css, ms-word

we are attempting to display information contained in a MS Word file directly on our website.

We are currently doing this by taking the MS Word file and saving it as an .html file then in dreamweaver we apply the css stylesheet.

Problem: although centered, the MS Word content appears not to be fitting within the container/page since the they both have specified widths and the background has a contrasting color - when the MS Word content is pasted into the dreamweaver file, it appears to take up the whole screen. The MS file was created using the 2011 version for Mac.

The webpage that we are trying to fix is: http://www.crediteducationprogram.org/cfiles/client-demo.htm

Please help us and thanks in advance!

The html code is too long to past here but here is the CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
}

a.hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Arial" Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;  
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Arial" Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: white;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Arial" Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    color: black;
}

h3 {
    font-family: "Arial" Gadget, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color: black;
}
























/*Main CSS*/

html {
background-color: #339;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}


.noborder {
    border-left-style: none !important;
}

.leftedge {
    border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
}
.topleft {
    border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.topright {
    border-radius: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
}
.bottomleft {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
}
.bottomright {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
}
.rightedge {
    border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
}



#container {
                position: relative;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 80%;
width: 982.5px;
background: white;
}

#container #maintext {
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

#main {
    text-align:left;
}

#main p {
    text-align:left;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;

}

#main a {
    text-align:justify !important;
}

#main p {
    text-align:justify !important;
}


#footer {
    background-color: #36c;
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
    font-size: small;
    display: block;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}

#container2 {
                position: relative;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 80%;
width: 982.5px;
}



#footer2 {
    background-color: #609;
width: 982.5px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: small;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#footer2 ul {
    text-align: left;
         height: auto;
    float: left;
}


#footer2 ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#footer2 ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0px 8px 8px 8px;
}

#footer2 ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


#container #footer3 {
    font-size:  small;
    color: #666;
}
```

Comment: You need to first narrow it down to the smallest program necessary to reproduce the issue. Unfortunately MS Word and Dreamweaver both puke out thousands of lines of unnecessary code so that will take you so time. But, as it is, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. See: [mcve]

Comment: At a guess - and it's only a guess - your problem is that MS Word includes reams and reams of inline style definition, which will basically overrule anything Dreamweaver tries to apply in a stylesheet. You can try stripping out all inline styles by using 'Find & Replace' in Dreamweaver - searching for and removing 'Attribute: style' - and see how the result looks then.

Comment: @MikeK That solved the problem, THANKS A MILLION!!